# Expecting Member Declaration

Tags: kotlin, corda

I am trying to build a kotlin file (Corda) but running into the following error:

> e:
>   /Users/pro/Documents/Code/Corda/Tutorials/Kotlin/cordapp-template-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/template/App.kt:
>   (59, 5): Expecting member declaration e:
>   /Users/pro/Documents/Code/Corda/Tutorials/Kotlin/cordapp-template-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/template/App.kt:
>   (59, 11): Expecting member declaration e:
>   /Users/pro/Documents/Code/Corda/Tutorials/Kotlin/cordapp-template-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/template/App.kt:
>   (59, 17): Expecting member declaration e:
>   /Users/pro/Documents/Code/Corda/Tutorials/Kotlin/cordapp-template-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/template/App.kt:
>   (59, 19): Expecting member declaration

Here is a snippet of line 59:

```
 // A transaction is considered valid if the verify() function of the contract of each of the transaction's input
    // and output states does not throw an exception.

    // Our Create Command
    Class Create: CommandData //Line 59
```

I am unsure of how to debug this and will appreciate any pointers on this

Comment: The `class` keyword should be lowercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As zsmb13 says, the `class` keyword should have a lower-case `c` (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html).