# What is "expected member declaration" when syntax is correct?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, compiler-errors

So, I wanted to implement a simple **database handler** class for my Android Studio project with **Kotlin**. Little did I know when I eye-rolled towards my "what even is kotlin" developer mates, that this hipster choice would lead me to lengthy damnation.
I decided to start out by copy-pasting the [code Google suggests](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#DbHelper) for a DB Helper utilizing the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.

*Naturally*, I started getting this unreasonable error
[image]
for each of the **closing brackets** `}` in *3 different methods* containing what looked like perfectly valid syntax.
[image]

Of course, I spent over a day checking every single piece of annoying Gradle build property that seems to be there only to increase the chances of something being off, as if it were a perfectly designed developer-Limbo build system from Hell. But every little check was to no avail, as I had no build errors and the "Expecting member" errors kept showing up.

Decided not to quit however, I even attempted to change my implementation to use the more Kotlin-friendly `anko.db` route, full code below.

```
package com.example.john.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import org.jetbrains.anko.db.*

class DBHandler(context: Context) : ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper(context, "POIEncounters", null, 1) {

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        db?.createTable("Encounter", true, "id" to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY + UNIQUE, "Name" to TEXT)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db?.dropTable("Encounter", true)
    }

    override fun onDowngrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion)
    }

}
```

As Divine Order dictates in the Developer Limbo, there was **no change** at all. Every time I click `Build` I am fooled by the syntax checker's underhanded reassurances, as the compiler denies my salvation. Even more amazingly. the errors persist **even if I comment-out the entire bodies of the overridden methods**.

At this point I am so beyond despair that I have fallen to the lowest level of the abyss: rejecting my ego and asking for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those not brave enough to witness the process, **TLDR** at the end.

The answer is given by my own self, after 3 endless epochs (*see: days*) in this unbuildable hellish dimension, and written at 3am with the sole company of a bottle of Glenfiddich whisky joined in the dark by the sounds of my demonized keyboard clacking.

The usual suspects of [easy-to-miss spelling errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46759315/1091818), [invalid constructor usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44368763/1091818) have been discarded over and over as I descend into madness, now fairly certain that even if someone where to copy my exact code, they might not even be getting this error.

I even tried tried downgrading Kotlin itself, in delusional hopes of a bug in its compiler bringing forth all these insistent mutterings of *"Expecting declaration"*...
In a last insane attempt I even tried importing my code into a different infernal machination of an IDE, just to see if the apocryphal messages would follow me there, in **Intellij IDEA**...

After one more hour of torment to align the new project's build files and other horrid properties causing minor issues... *They did.*
[image]

I was about to give up and when I spotted this strange, unfamiliar sign on Intellij's syntax checker:
`Found byte-order-mark in the middle of a file <...>`
[image]

***SON. OF. A. BENCH.***

Now, at this incredibly agonizing part of my journey, much like many other devs living in the blissful heaven-like area of *"typing code that is parsed the way you read it"*, I had *no forking idea* what a **BOM** is.

Yet the celestial IDEA even gives us the forbidden, dark knowledge of a wikipedia link, which I followed in foolish innocence, to see a maddening, curious fragment of the cosmos which man was not meant to lay eyes upon...
[image]

***What the fork.***

My fingers trembled and started moving in a feverish climax. I heard myself cackling as I submerged myself in the unreal madness of a last irrational hope...

I deleted the 3 methods. Purged them all an in unholy, functio-cidal frenzy and gazed up the empty class, free of the invisible, sickening infection.

`Build. *click* Success.`

---

I **rewrote each and every one one of the methods by hand**, without copy-pasting or touching any devil-infected piece of vile text, while listening to the fiendish, otherworldly "Dethklok Awaken" calls. And that was it. It worked. I am free, ascending into Elysium, whiskey in one hand and tears dropping to the Flame Below.
Yet, empty and disappointed. For the the cunning shade was not a tangible foe, but an ephemeral force, looming inside the Self...
With this answer, I hope no one has to face the same mistake I did. Not unprepared at least.

---

***TLDR***: There was a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character that was causing the error. Intellij clarified the cause, while Android Studio didn't. Deleted and re-wrote problematic parts by hand without copy-pasting anything and it worked.

***Epilogue***: Everyday we stray further from ASCII's light.

Comment: Ping me when you write your next novel... I'll read you till the last dot.  :-)

Comment: Could be a non-breaking space also, or some other invisible character